# Update the Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.0.0-experimental1 to 1.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am trying to update the Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from  1.0.0-experimental1 to  1.0.0
but after Upgrade the NuGet I get this error

> cs5001 program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point

In the CSC file.

I am using visual studio 2022.
windows 10 version 1909.
OS Build 18363.1734.

Comment: [Known problem](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1877), it's being worked on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I delete my "User profile" from windows and created it again and the problem fixed.